# Mass deploy Managed ActiveX control written in C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, activex, clickonce

I have created a managed ActiveX control in C# (.NET 4.0) that is accessed by Office VBA (currently being called from VBA code in Dynamics).  However, when looking for a method to deploy this to the masses in our company (and keep it updated), I cannot find an efficient way of doing this.

At first, I thought that I could do this somehow through ClickOnce, but after reading some articles, I don't think this will work.

Are there any suggestions?  PowerShell perhaps?

I will need to update this control somewhat frequently as we add new functionality.

Any advice is greatly welcomed.

Thanks for your time,

Rob

Answer (score 3):

Don't rule out ClickOnce just yet. The issue with ClickOnce is that it installs apps *per-user* rather than per-machine/system-wide. Because COM/ActiveX registration is typically machine/system wide, i.e. the registry entries are under HKLM, ClickOnce doesn't support it (due to permissions required to modify the HKLM part of the registry).

But since Windows 2000 it's possible to register COM objects in the user part of the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` maps to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` which is the same as `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

So, using something like [RegSvrEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/regsvrex.aspx) you should be able to ascertain the registry entries you need to create under `HKCU`.  When you've done this, find a way of triggering this HKCU reg update when the ClickOnce install/update happens.

Comment: Hello Duncan, thank you for the response.  I read through that article, but don't think it directly applies for what I'm after.  The hosting application is going to be Dynamics (or, for a similar illustration, Excel).  Within Excel, you go to the Code window, select Tools -> References, and add my ActiveX (C# 4.0) control (which was registered with regasm).  I was hoping to avoid running regasm on 75+ computers.  And, not sure how to update my ActiveX control once its deployed to them all.  Am I missing something from that article or is there any other direction you can point me in?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'll update the answer. I was thinking about registering COM objects under the user's registry (HKCU) rather than the machine (HKLM)

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for the update.  So I am wondering if I should create a PowerShell/WMI solution that uses RegSvrEx.  Interesting idea...

Comment: Actually thinking about it, ClickOnce is triggered by a stub EXE that launches before your app's EXE, which I guess you don't have (yours is just a DLL I assume). In any case the local COM registration maybe helpful - perhaps your delivery mechanism can be something simple triggered from a logon script.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [`regasm.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) utility:

```
regasm.exe /codebase foo.dll
```

where `foo.dll` is the managed assembly containing the ActiveX control that you want to expose.